# Get all points in Highcharts scatter plot?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Working with Highcharts, I know how to [get one point by ID](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.get):

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
var point = chart.get(code);
```

But how do I get all the points in a chart as an array?

The reason I want this is so that I can set selected state on the chosen point: `point.setState('hover')` and clear it on all the other points.

Comment: did you try chart.series[0].data

Comment: I've put the same in answer so that others will find it helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the chart object which you got i.e

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

you have every aspect about the chart in it

Here is the part where you can find the plotted data

```
chart.series[0].data
```